# What's "(oft) with poss"?

Tags: word-meaning, dictionaries

Both

> [with poss]

and

> [oft with poss]

are instructions in Collins Dictionary.

I can understand "oft" = "often", but what is "poss"? The dictionary doesn't give an answer, at least I didn't find out.

example: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/identity

and: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=683&bih=318&ei=kfLjWsz1OOvZjwSJwLaQBg&q=collins+oft+with+poss&oq=collins+oft+with+poss&gs_l=psy-ab.3.o..47839.47839.0.49013.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.xuaq9zkz14I

Comment: They mean that this noun is used with possessive words and constructions like **your**, **mine**, **Zhang's**. "Oft" stands for "often"

Comment: @CowperKettle - You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean that this noun is used with possessive words and constructions like **your, my, Zhang's**. "Oft" stands for "often".